# Linq2Sql not showing in C# Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have a Asp.NET C# Project where i have created a Linq2SQL Model.

In a file i have to use it and somewhy its not showing up in intelicense form visual studio.

when i try to use `InformitoDatabaseDataContext db = new InformitoDatabaseDataContext();` it doesnt recognize InformitoDatabaseDataContext.

The name of the .dbml file is InformitoDatabase.dbml

[Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7jGZ.png)

[Image of Project (Update)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9Uch.png)

What can i do to "connect" the dbml file to my class?

Comment: I think may be it is not present in App_Code folder.
Move your dbml file to App_Code Folder.

Comment: You are creating it's object on Genral.cs class. Try creating it's object on Login.aspx.cs or any page code behind. May be your Genral.cs class have a different namespace.

Comment: I already tried that and doesnt solve the problem. Also i tried to create another dbml and doesnt work too.

Comment: create a new empty project and add LinqtoSql class and check it is accessible in the new project or not. May something is wrong in your current project.

Comment: I created an empty project and now it recongizes it, but it gives a error when i start it. __The type 'System.Data.Linq.DataContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'__

Comment: I have posted the answer, check it.

Comment: @xRed: So did you follow the error message, and add a reference to System.Data.Linq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution, the problem is that you are missing `InformitoDatabaseDataContext.designer.cs` class
Check you are missing it or not.

I just add a dbml file to aap code folder, it consist of three files,

1. informitodatabase.dbml
2. informitodatabase.dbml.layout
3. informitodatabase.designer.cs

when  I add a new file in the root directoy it misses the designer file
When I created the object of both the files, the file which is present in App_Code folder is accessible while other one is not accessible.

See the below image file, I added two files in App_Code folder and two in the Root Directory.

[image]

Comment: Thanks that was the problem. The file was created in root dir and it should have been create in App_Code. Thanks mate u saved my day :)

Comment: @xRed you are welcome :). It looks like a bug in VS, it should add the  designer.cs file otherwise don't allow the user to add it on Root Directory.

Answer (score 3):

I *suspect* the problem is that you're using `...DataContent` when normally it would be `...DataContext`, with an `x` instead of an `n`.

(Your screenshot shows the failure - with a different name from the one in the question - but not where the context itself is declared, which leaves us guessing somewhat... but as `UserChosenPrefixDataContext` is the default, it's highly likely that's what's wrong.)

EDIT: You've now changed your post to talk about `SchoolDatabaseDataContext`, but in the screenshot highlighting the failure, you're referring to `InformitoDatabaseDataContent`.

Comment: Sorry i misstyped that, but it still gives the error. Its like it doesnt recognise that object

Comment: @xRed: As I've just edited, the same typo is in the screenshot. If you can show a screenshot showing `InformitoDatabaseDataContext` not being recognized (and with no sign of a suggestion of a `using` directive), that would be a different matter.

Comment: I know but i tried it too there, i changed everywhere to __SchoolDatabaseDataContext__ , still gives the error

Comment: @xRed: Well it's unclear where `SchoolDatabase` comes in at all, given that it isn't shown anywhere in your project. Instead it's `InformitoDatabase`. It would *really* help if you'd be consistent. It's also not clear whether `General.cs` is in the same project or not - perhaps you're just missing a `using` directive?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the default is DataContext, not DataContent.

Comment: Sorry i misstyped that, but it still gives the error. Its like it doesnt recognise that object

Comment: Take a look at the generated code from the DBML file, it should show you the class name.

Comment: You mean, you can't expand the dbml in the screenshot? It has the triangle next to it - you should be able to. Try re-opening the DBML in designer and making a small change, then re-saving it.

Comment: I can expand it and open it, its in the .cs file that it doesnt show up